# Django inclison tag, endless pagination doesn't work

Tags: django, tags, pagination

i have a Django projet with django-enless-pagination. i would like to paginate some entries, i create inclusion tag witch i run in my view, i pass some data to generate this entries.

In partial i run

```
{% paginate entries %}
```

and i have error

```
 Exception Type:     KeyError
            Exception Value:    u'request'
            Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dispackages/django/template/context.py in __getitem__, line 57
```

i dont have any idea what is worng. I need help. Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

i sovled,

evertything was becuse i am a new ;)
i don't know that i need pass a context with data to view in inclusion tag, for that a tag should be like that

```
   from django import template
   from dls.apps.products.models import Art
   from dls.apps.userprofiles.models import Artist
  `from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
```

register = template.Library();

@register.inclusion_tag('shop/templatetags/product_by_art.html',
   takes_context=True)
   def partart(context,data):
    user = get_object_or_404(Artist,user__username=data);
    all_prod = Art.objects.filter(user__id=user.id,active=True);
        return {'all': all_prod,
                'request': context['request']}
   
context as a function parameter and request

Sorry for trouble, i must teach a liite more :)